# R plot: Bringing formatted values into expression() in base graphics legend

Tags: r, plot, legend

Following problem: I try to make a legend where I will have something like:
ɛ = 5 L / (mol cm). The number however is calculated, here a minimal example:

```
plot(rnorm(10,3),rnorm(10,3))
epsilon.calc <- mean(rnorm(10,3))
legend("topleft",bty="n",legend=paste("epsilon=",format(epsilon.calc,digits=5),"L/(molcm)"))
legend("bottom",bty="n",legend=expression(epsilon,paste(format(epsilon.calc,digits=5)),"L/(molcm)"))
```

If I use the first legend I can paste the number (epsilon.calc), if I use legend 2 I can express epsilon in the right manner. 
Anyone an idea to combine how to combine those expression() and paste() in one legend?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I think you want:

```
legend("bottom",bty="n",legend=c(bquote(epsilon ==.(format(epsilon.calc, digits=5))),
                                 expression( L/(mol %.% cm) )
       )                        )
```

It's better to learn to use plotmath with minimal use of `paste()`. `bquote` is the simplest mechanism for getting evaluations done but it can also be done with `substitute`. `paste` inside an expression call is actually a different function than `paste` "outside" one.

[image]

This is the one line version:

```
legend("bottom",bty="n",
    legend=bquote(epsilon ==.(format(epsilon.calc, digits=5))~(L/(mol %.% cm))
     )           )
```

Comment: That is working fine, how can I receive the whole text in one line, right now the unit on a second line?

Comment: Take out the comma and the expression call. Link the tokens with a tilde (`~`).

Comment: The one line version is not working for me (maybe because Mac?) and in your example picture the unit isn't expressed properly as well.

Comment: Had one too many parentheses in the dot-call. Nothing to do with Macs. I'm using one myself. But about the units, ... you are not particularly clear about what is "proper".

Comment: Now it`s working perfect! I meant because in your postet plot picture the unit in the top legend looks like L/(mol%*%cm), however it's working very well now. Thank you!!

Comment: That was a side effect of my trying to put in a plotmath operator inside a regular paste() call. Not surprisingly if looked bad.